# Measure data completeness in Pandas/Pyspark and groupby date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a data quality project and I need to measure the data completeness of my dataframe per date.
I have something like:

```
Date         A       B
2021-06-18   x       y
2021-06-18   NaN     y
2021-06-20   x       y
2021-06-20   x       y
2021-06-20   x       y
```

I can measure completeness of whole dataframe  with pandas using:

```
print (test_df.isna().sum().sum() / test_df.size * 100)
```

But now what I want is to have something like this:

```
Date         NaPercent
2021-06-18   25%
2021-06-20   0%
```

I tried using:

```
test_df.groupby(['date']).isna().sum().sum() / test_df.size * 100
```

or

```
test_df.isna().groupby(['date']).sum().sum() / test_df.size * 100
```

but still not working.
I have been looking but not finding a solution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your formula into a lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), as follows:

As you don't want to count the `NaN` values on `Date` column, we can exclude it by setting it as index in the formula.  The calculation result is further converted into string and add the `%` symbol.

```
(test_df.groupby('Date')
        .apply(lambda x: (x.set_index('Date').isna().sum().sum() / x.set_index('Date').size * 100).astype(str) + '%')
        .reset_index(name='NaPercent')
)
```

**Another solution:**

```
nan_in_group = test_df.set_index('Date').isna().groupby(level=0).sum().sum(axis=1) 

group_size = test_df.set_index('Date').groupby(level=0).size() * (test_df.columns.size - 1)

df_result = ((nan_in_group / group_size * 100).astype(str) + '%').reset_index(name='NaPercent')

print(df_result)
```

**Result:**

```
         Date NaPercent
0  2021-06-18     25.0%
1  2021-06-20      0.0%
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
grouped = test_df.groupby('Date')
sizes = grouped.size().values * len(test_df.columns)

num_of_nans = sizes - grouped.count().sum(axis=1)
out = num_of_nans / sizes
out.to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'NaPercent'})
```

Output:

```
            NaPercent
Date                 
2021-06-18       0.25
2021-06-20       0.00
```

Comment: It did not give me the expected result but it helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking at this for pySpark solution can refer below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("num_records", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("date"))) \
  .withColumn("completeness_a", 100 - (count(when(col("a").isNull() | (col("a") == ''), col("a"))).over(Window.partitionBy("date")) / col("num_records") * 100)) \
  .withColumn("completeness_b", 100 - (count(when(col("b").isNull() | (col("b") == ''), col("b"))).over(Window.partitionBy("date")) / col("num_records") * 100)) \
  .select("date", "completeness_a", "completeness_b").distinct().orderBy("date")
```

We basically first add a column as number or records per date and use this column to find completeness percentage against count of records (for a particular column say col. a) when it's either null or is empty.

Should give something similar to:

```
Date        num_records     completeness_a    completeness_b
2022-01-07          50               55.34             23.54
2022-01-08          23               32.67               100
```